# Things to do when taking over an application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-applications, web

We are taking over an application from a differnet team. 
we have just 5 days to learn everything possible about the application from this team. 
This original team will not be available after these five days.

At this point, we don't even know the size or the complexity of the application. All we know is it's a j2ee application. My guess is it's a fairly big application. I have been a developer the past few years and I have never undertaken anything like this before. So I am not even sure where to start.

My questions are but not limited to:

1. Where do I start?
2. What kind of questions should I be asking?
3. Is there any tools/methodologies out there that is used in these situations?
4. Any books I can read about it?

Comment: this is more opinion based then any solid answer.

Comment: @jgr208 I apologize but I looked at all the available sites and I couldn't find anything that would fit my question completely. So I decided to post it here.

Comment: this should be posted on a forum or like a software engineering stack exchange.

Comment: If you have to ask questions, there is only one: "What is not in laid down in the project documentation?" As soon as they start talking, hightail it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I have been a developer the past few years and I have never undertaken anything like this before

Don't worry too much, everyone has been in this position at some point of time . There's no universal recipe for this kind of code take over. And it will probably take lots of hours of reading, debugging, understanding, reworking, supporting this code later on but ... so what? It's a nice challenge.

Anyway to start with ask them several main things:

1) how to build and deploy it to a clean machine (clear step-by-step guide), or to a set of clean machines (if the app is distributed somehow). If you're able to do this, you'll get much more confidence you can manage this app yourself (even though you may not understand it at first);

2) any dependencies on external systems that the app has (web services it calls/consumes, any external systems it communicates to, meaning outgoing communications of this app);

3) any web services or resources it exposes/provides, and who calls them (incoming communications);

4) any DBs (relational or not) it uses (it connects to);

5) what's the business logic of this app, what does it do, how it does it (high level architectural decisions; layers), overall technical things like these.

Answer (score 2):

Peter covered most of the good points. I work on a web based application myself, here's my 2¢:

Tools that come in handy for me are:

[Yourkit](https://www.yourkit.com/) - For profiling the application, as well as analyzing any heap dumps it spits out.

[Splunk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q1F4J8viBrM) - Especially if your app spews out a lot of log files. Digging out the log files from nfs and opening in a slow text editor is primitive, splunk is the way to go. Splunk has excellent search functionality, and you can search thru multiple log files. ctrl+f thru each log file is a pain. You can unearth valuable data, such as how often a login API call is being made to your app in a certain time window. It would be suggested to have a splunk instance running alongside your production system.

Few of things that you could perhaps inquire from the departing team:

1. The dependency management system. Does it rely on maven, gradle or ant? Where does it get its artifacts from? Is it a locally hosted Artifactory or does it fetch them from the web.
2. The various API channels to the app. Apart from the UI, is there a shell API, a perl or python one, or a java one, and how are those maintained.
3. Know the testing framework. Do you use junit and mockito? Is there a perl based testing framework? Also know the code coverage tools in use.
4. The build framework. If it's a web application, it's probably deployed onto a java servlet, and for that a .war file is needed. There must be a build system like Jenkins or ElectricCommander in place which runs compilations and tests and what not and finally generates a war file. Assuming you guys are going to be handling this system, and not an integrations/release team, make sure you know how it works in case it goes down one day and the builds are a sea of red. We've been there.

Really, the departing team should have sufficient documentation for this already, that would be the best handover.